# Define header fields for variables in rbind

Tags: r, rbind

I am attempting to write results from ccf (cross correlation function) to a data frame and print. This code works for the first iteration:

```
ccftable <- data.frame()
for (i in unique(Data$SeasAlltxt)){
  subdata1 <- subset(Data, SeasAlltxt == i)
  for (j in unique(Data$ALSCIDtxtall)){
    subdata2 <- subset(subdata1, ALSCIDtxtall == j)
    ccfvalues = ccf(x = subdata2$NO3_AVG, y = subdata2$MaxDepth_m, plot = FALSE, lag.max = 0, na.action = na.pass, ylab = "CCF: Lake NO3 vs. Snow Depth", main = paste0(j, ": ", i))
    ccftable <- rbind(ccftable,c(i,j,ccfvalues))
    print (ccftable)
    write.csv(ccftable, file = "CCF_NO3vsSnowDepth_Stats.csv")
  }
}
```

On subsequent iterations, the rbind function fails because it sees different names for the first two headers fields. This is the output from "print (ccftable)":

```
  X.Winter. X.020058x. acf        type            n.used lag    seriessnames 
2 Winter    020058x    0.1454731  correlation     20     0      X subdata2$NO3_AVG & subdata2$MaxDepth_m

Error in match.names(clabs, nmi) : names do not match previous names
```

This first two header fields are inappropriately named "X.Winter." and "X.020058x.". These should be named "SeasAlltxt" and "ALSCIDtxtall", which are the field names for variables i and j. If I can make this change, then rbind will see the same header names and append appropriately on each iteration.

Any suggestions for how to accomplish this?

Comment: Maybe use the function designed for changing the names?

Comment: Which function is that?

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions. I am not sure where/how I would use `names<-` or `setNames` to do this, please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the column names using

```
ccftable <- data.frame()
for (i in unique(Data$SeasAlltxt)){
  subdata1 <- subset(Data, SeasAlltxt == i)
  for (j in unique(Data$ALSCIDtxtall)){
    subdata2 <- subset(subdata1, ALSCIDtxtall == j)
    ccfvalues = ccf(x = subdata2$NO3_AVG, y = subdata2$MaxDepth_m, plot = FALSE, lag.max = 0, na.action = na.pass, ylab = "CCF: Lake NO3 vs. Snow Depth", main = paste0(j, ": ", i))
    tempvalues <- data.frame(c(i,j,ccfvalues))
    colnames(tempvalues) <- c('SeasAlltxt', 'ALSCIDtxtall', 'acf', 'type', 'n.used', 'lag', 'series', 'snames')
    ccftable <- rbind(ccftable,tempvalues)
    print (ccftable)
    write.csv(ccftable, file = "CCF_NO3vsSnowDepth_Stats.csv")
  }
}
```

Also you should write your csv table at the end of your loops, not at every row.

Comment: I tried this (shown below) and receive the same error.

Comment: Use the colnames function on both of your data frames to see where the mismatch in names occurs.

Comment: I put this in the second line `colNames(ccftable) <- c('SeasAlltxt', 'ALSCIDtxtall', 'acf', 'type', 'n.used', 'lag', 'series', 'snames')`

Comment: Sure, now what are the column names for

    c(i,j,ccfvalues)

Comment: I know that mismatch occurs with the first two field names. I need these field names to remain as 'SeasAlltxt' and 'ALSCIDtxtall'. However, they are changing with each iteration of i an j.

Comment: colnames gives me an error: Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("SeasAlltxt", "ALSCIDtxtall",  : 
  'names' attribute [8] must be the same length as the vector [0]

Comment: So probably your vector c(i,j,ccfvalues) doesn't have column names. This is actually just a vector of two numbers and values. Try the code I will post above

Comment: I get error:  Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ""acf"" to a data.frame

Comment: Perfect! Many thanks, also for the tip to move write.csv out of the loop.